# How to pass enum types to Azure Logic app?

Tags: c#, azure, enums, azure-logic-apps

Here is my context. I'm passing a object to my Logic App. And my object has a attribute of type 'enum'. I'm comparing the enum attribute using "Condition" in my logic app with specific type and performing some operations.

Ex: enum AppointmentType { New, Scheduled, Postponed, Completed, Cancelled }

When I pass as enum type, I could see the output as "0".   Is there anyway to pass the enum type to my logic app?

Comment: Enums are just aliases over an underlying type, by default int. You can pass any valid underlying value to an `enum` variable or parameter, even if that value isn't defined. Just pass the underlying value to your app. You can use the [Enum.IsDefined](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined(v=vs.110).aspx) method to validate the value

Comment: I'm not getting your point. Could you please elaborate little more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An enum is derived from a number value, this can be `byte`, `Int16`, `Int32` or `Int64`, by default `Int32` is used.

Your type can be rewritten as:

```
enum AppointmentType : System.Int32 //Implied by default
{ 
    New = 0, 
    Scheduled = 1, 
    Postponed = 2, 
    Completed = 3, 
    Cancelled = 4 
}
```

So when value `0` is passed to your logic app, `AppointmentType.New` was meant.

If value 3 was passed, `AppointmentType.Completed` was meant.

---

**TL;DR** You can pass enums around by using their numerical value.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Now got another doubt. Will post as new question :)